# VK Java SDK - Can't parse JSON response

Tags: java, json, вконтакте, sdk

Пытаюсь получить список постов на стене сообщества используя Java SDK. На локальной машине все работает без проблем, на удаленном сервере возникает следующая ошибка:

c

```
om.vk.api.sdk.client.ApiRequest         : Invalid JSON: // тут JSON (проверил онлайн - он валидный)

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:942) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:994) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar!/:na]
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:600) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:446) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
com.vk.api.sdk.exceptions.ClientException: Can't parse json response
        at com.vk.api.sdk.client.ApiRequest.executeWithoutRetry(ApiRequest.java:104)
```

Может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой и знает в чем дело?

UPD:
Запрос делаю следующим образом:

```
public GetResponse findContent(int ownerId, int size) {
        GetResponse response = null;

        try {
            response = vk.wall()
                    .get(actor)
                    .ownerId(ownerId)
                    .extended(false)
                    .count(size)
                    .execute();
        } catch (ApiException | ClientException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: в таком случае проблема с соединением скорее всего... т.е. не физическим соединением, а в сетевых настройках сервака. а другие запросы на серваке выполняются нормально?

Comment: @Дмитрий, да, другие запросы выполняются нормально. Дело в том, что и запрос на выгрузку постов из сообществ частично работает - часть постов выгружается без проблем

Comment: Какой запрос отправляете? Какой ответ получаете?

Comment: @Bakhuss, добавил в вопрос

Comment: no protocol - ошибка в url. Может кодировка, может ещё что.